# Table layout with textviews

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with 3 columns, and I have 3 string arrays. I want that every column have a textview per cell from the string array.
My code so far:

```
TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    prices.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    prices.bringToFront();
    table =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table);
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        TableRow tr =  new TableRow(this);
        TextView c1 = new TextView(this);
        c1.setText(table[i]);
        TextView c2 = new TextView(this);
        c2.setText (table[i]);
        TextView c3 = new TextView(this);
        c3.setText(table[i]);
        tr.addView(c1);
        tr.addView(c2);
        tr.addView(c3);
        prices.addView(tr);
```

It looks like this:

[image]

My string arrays:

```
<string-array name="column1">
    <item >5</item>
    <item >7</item>
    <item >10</item>
    <item >18</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="column2">
    <item >10, 20</item>
    <item >15, 13</item>
    <item >53, 65</item>
    <item >58, 32</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="column3">
    <item >10, 44</item>
    <item >25, 01</item>
    <item >30, 32</item>
    <item >43, 12</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to every column display numbers from the right string array. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really know what your problem is. But you could put your data in a multi-dimensional array and wrap your current loop in a second loop to iterate through rows and cols. Is that what you meant? Provide us some more information if you need further help. Greetz.

Comment: What are the values you wanna store in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I managed to make it:

```
TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    String[] column1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column1);
    String[] column2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column2);
    String[] column3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column3);
    prices.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    prices.bringToFront();
    for(int i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
        TableRow tr =  new TableRow(this);
        TextView c1 = new TextView(this);
        c1.setText(column1[i]);
        TextView c2 = new TextView(this);
        c2.setText(column2[i]);
        TextView c3 = new TextView(this);
        c3.setText(column3[i]);
        tr.addView(c1);
        tr.addView(c2);
        tr.addView(c3);
        prices.addView(tr);
    }
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data and how you want to present it. If your data array is just 1d, and it looks like it is, you just need to add a second for loop to look into further cells.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    TableRow tr =  new TableRow(this);
    for (int j=0; j<columns; j++ {
        TextView c1 = new TextView(this);
        c1.setText(table[i+j]);
        tr.addView(c1);
    }
    prices.addView(tr);
}
```

or something like that.  This populates the cells of "table" one row at a time.  So it really depends on your data organization/format.  Also, you need to set column and row size, and of course check for nulls in case your data set is not a full row * column number of entries.

Comment: This is not a perfect answer. What if he doesn't wanna store value of `i+j` in each cell?

Comment: You set two loop, it's fine. But the way you are entering values is wrong. OP hasn't said what exact values he wants to store in table. So can't store value of i or j or i+j in cells

Comment: @Apurva I'm sorry, I don't understand you.  From the looks of OP's first 4 data entries, it looks like number in string or charsequence format.  I was answering based on what information I had.  That said, the code I wrote did not store the "value of i+j in each cell".  you can clearly see it is the value of 'table[i+j]'.  so, the first row would be '5,7,10' and the second row starts with '18,...' assuming we're still using 3 columns.  I fail to see the problem, except I did not flesh out the code with a tabel.length check.

Comment: It does the same when I run it. I edited the post with the string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

your code adds the same `i` value to all 3 textviews in the same row. this is more of writing a variation of your for loop instead of your current loop.. try this instead.

```
  table =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table);
        String[][] tableData=new String [][]{getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column1),
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column2),getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column3)
    }
        for(int i = 0; i < tableData[0].length; i++){
             TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j=0;j<tableData.length;j++){              
             TextView c1 = new TextView(this);      
             c1.setText(tableData[j][i]); 
             tr.addView(c1);
            }
            prices.addView(tr);
        }
```

thus should give you different values in each column. just vary the for loop to achieve what you want. you are filling data row wise. keep that in mind while iterating through the arrays

Comment: No your answer is **wrong**. Your output will be **Row1** `0 | 1 | 2` **Row2** `0 | 1 | 2` **Row3** `0 | 1 | 2` i.e. all columns gonna have same value.

Comment: This will have the same effect on output as the OP has and your inner for loop will be of no use

Comment: You set two loop, it's fine. But the way you are entering values is wrong. OP hasn't said what exact values he wants to store in table. So can't store value of i or j or i+j in cells

Comment: It does the same when I run it. I edited the post with the string arrays.